ClientFetchError on GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
In my project I'm using the spotify-web-api-ts-sdk to request data from spotify as well as next.js and auth.js and therefore I used the example_next from spotifys github repo.
I'm experiencing the following error (probably after my maxAge from the session is reached?):
GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    fetchData @ client.js:44
    getSession @ react.js:105
    getAccessToken @ clientInstance.ts:23
    getOrCreateAccessToken @ clientInstance.ts:19
    makeRequest @ SpotifyApi.js:99
    getRequest @ EndpointsBase.js:11
    getPlaybackState @ PlayerEndpoints.js:10
    eval @ usePlayback.ts:11
    Show 5 more frames
    Show less
clientInstance.ts:23 ClientFetchError: Failed to fetch. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#autherror
    at fetchData (client.js:49:22)
    at async getSession (react.js:105:21)
    at async NextAuthStrategy.getAccessToken (clientInstance.ts:23:26)
    at async SpotifyApi.makeRequest (SpotifyApi.js:99:33)
    at async PlayerEndpoints.getRequest (EndpointsBase.js:11:16)
window.console.error @ app-index.js:35
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:41
fetchData @ client.js:49
await in fetchData (async)
getSession @ react.js:105
getAccessToken @ clientInstance.ts:23
getOrCreateAccessToken @ clientInstance.ts:19
makeRequest @ SpotifyApi.js:99
getRequest @ EndpointsBase.js:11
getPlaybackState @ PlayerEndpoints.js:10
eval @ usePlayback.ts:11
Show 7 more frames
Show less
usePlayback.

I could find some people online specifying the same error but no answer there fixed it for me. Most of them said getSession() has to be used on client side what already is the case for me (because they did it in the example and I copied it). Right now I believe the problem orginates somewhere from the code in the example but ig other people already used this code successfully, so I'm not really sure.
I'm just developing my project further and at some point I need to manually logout and then login again because the session can't be renewed. Based on the code I would expect the site to force me to login with spotify again.
  public getOrCreateAccessToken(): Promise<AccessToken> {
    return this.getAccessToken();
  }

  public async getAccessToken(): Promise<AccessToken> {
    const session: any = await getSession();
    if (!session) {
      return {} as AccessToken;
    }

    if (session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
      await signIn("spotify");
      return this.getAccessToken();
    }
...

but the code already gives the error when trying to getSession() so it doesn't get far enough.
